# Convergence or Divergence of $c_n = \sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac{1}{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I need to prove the convergence or divergence of the sequence $$c_n = \sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac{1}{k}$$ and in the case of convergence, determine the limit.

I wrote out several of the partial sums and it seems as if this sequence should converge for sufficiently large $n$. However, I'm not sure how to calculate the limit.

Comment: This is approximately $$H_{n^2}-H_n \sim \log n^2 - \log n = \log n$$ hence the sequence is divergent.

Comment: It is easy to show that it is bounded below by the harmonic sum.

Comment: "Aye, Calypso, the places you've been to, the men who have served you, so long and so well...."... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwik5qzuw7fWAhXGZiYKHeUNDnk4ChC3AggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dq3EE83q6tzw&usg=AFQjCNFeFnQ3__q2ITPt6yBscRXpqWtZ6A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$, it is well-known that $H_n = \ln(n) + \gamma + O(1/n)$.  You have
$$ c_n = H_{n^2} - H_{n-1} = \ln(n) + O(1/n)$$
So it does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\ln{n}+C+\gamma_n,$$
where $\gamma_n\rightarrow0$.